# Reading a Kafka topic using streaming api in Pyspark - Issue not able to write to console or send to any other sink

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am kind of stuck, I read a Kafka topic using the spark streaming API in pyspark and am then trying to push it to a sink either a console or another Kafka topic, I am not sure what I am doing wrong but the whole process is somewhat stuck and does not do anything. I checked there are messages on the topic etc. I am able to read and continue if I use a java based consumer but somehow for pyspark not able to consume and output the messages. I put the code in a zeppelin notebook too and the code is below.
Appreciate it if someone can please have a quick look and suggest what am i doing wrong

```
%pyspark

def foreach_function(df, epoch_id):
    print("I am here")
    #pass
  

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, TimestampType, StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
schema = StructType([
    StructField("orderId",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("quantity",IntegerType(),True), 
    StructField("order_VALUE",DoubleType(),True), 
    StructField("sku",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("sales_DATE",StringType(),True)
    ])
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "kafka.topic.orders") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
  .load()

df.printSchema()
dataDF = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
dataDF.printSchema()
orderDF = dataDF.select(from_json(col("value"),schema)).alias("data").select("data.*")
orderDF.printSchema()

orderDF.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").option("checkpointLocation", "/test/chkpt").start().awaitTermination()



Error
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)

root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

root
 |-- from_json(value): struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- orderId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- quantity: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- order_VALUE: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sku: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sales_DATE: string (nullable = true)

Fail to execute line 31: orderDF.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").option("checkpointLocation", "/test/chkpt").start().awaitTermination()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/1625186594615-0/zeppelin_python.py", line 158, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 31, in <module>
  File "/Users/test/software/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 103, in awaitTermination
    return self._jsq.awaitTermination()
  File "/Users/test/software/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/Users/test/software/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 137, in deco
    raise_from(converted)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: Writing job aborted.
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 85d72b5f-f1f5-4ad3-a8b4-cb986576ced2, runId = 229fed09-0c60-4eae-a296-7fbebb46f4d6]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[kafka.topic.orders]]: {"kafka.topic.orders":{"2":34,"1":31,"0":35}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe see if this helps first.
[pySpark Structured Streaming from Kafka does not output to console for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547463/pyspark-structured-streaming-from-kafka-does-not-output-to-console-for-debugging)

And i would try with just this:

```
writeStream
    .format("console")
    .start().awaitTermination()
```

Also double check if the message are getting produced after you start your consumer(above pyspark job), as you have "latest" flag.

Comment: Akhil , thanks.  I did try the suggestions, looking into the error I am seeing that the kafka offsets are continuously growing which means the code is reading the topic but somehow not printing to the console or writing to other sink
Identifier: [id = c0db7716-c3fd-4080-b93a-30fc810941ab, runId = 73e5de89-daf4-404f-9284-a9d394ea6930]
Current Committed Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[kafka.topic.orders]]: {"kafka.topic.orders":{"0":1300}}}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[kafka.topic.orders]]: {"kafka.topic.orders":{"0":1307}}}
Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Comment: I was able to make it work, I tried the script outside zeppelin using  spark-submit and it worked after I added the commons-pool2 jar.  I was able to see the full stacktraace using native spark-submit.  Thank you all.  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work, I tried the script outside zeppelin using spark-submit and it worked after I added the commons-pool2 jar. I was able to see the full stacktraace using native spark-submit. Thank you all.  org.apache.commons commons-pool2 2.10.0  –